# REST Web Service using Java and Jersey API: Unable to Read data from DB

Tags: sql, eclipse, rest, jersey

I am creating a REST Web Service using Java and Jersey API. The basic REST service works fine,but when I add in a DB connection it gives me a Class Not Found Exception and a SQL Exception - No driver found. I have included the ojdbc6.jar file in the Eclipse build path. Using the same code if I create a Java application it runs fine.
I have added my code below. Can some one plz suggest something.
EDIT: I included the jar file in the WEB-INF lib directory. But when I try to execute the code I get the following error: HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed

```
public class Note {

    private int noteId;
    private String content;
    private Date createdDate;

    public Note() {}

    public Note(int noteId, String content, Date createdDate) {
        this.noteId = noteId;
        this.content = content;
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public int getNoteId() {
        return noteId;
    }

    public void setNoteId(int noteId) {
        this.noteId = noteId;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Note [content=" + content + ", createdDate=" + createdDate
                + ", noteId=" + noteId + "]";
    }
}

public class NoteDAO {

    DatabaseAccess data;
    Connection connection;

    public NoteDAO()
    {
        try {
            data = new DatabaseAccess();
            connect();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void connect() throws SQLException
    {
        try
        {
            data.connect();
            connection = data.connection;
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Note getNoteById(int id) 
    {
        PreparedStatement prepStmt = null;
        try {
            String cSQL = "SELECT * FROM NOTE WHERE NOTEID = 12 ";
            prepStmt = connection.prepareStatement(cSQL);
            prepStmt.setInt(1, id); 
            ResultSet result = prepStmt.executeQuery();
            Note note = new Note();
            while (result.next())
            {
                note.setNoteId(result.getInt(1));
                note.setContent(result.getString(2));
                note.setCreatedDate( (Date) new java.util.Date(result.getDate(3).getTime()));
            }
            return note;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            prepStmt = null;
            return null;
        }
    }




}
@Path("/notes")
public class Notes {

    @Context
    UriInfo uriInfo;
    @Context
    Request request;

    NoteDAO dao = new NoteDAO();





    @Path("{note}")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Note getNote(
            @PathParam("note") String idStr) {
        int id = Integer.parseInt(idStr);

        Note note = dao.getNoteById(id);
        if(note==null)
            throw new RuntimeException("Get: Note with " + id +  " not found");
        return note;
    }


public class DatabaseAccess {

    Connection connection = null;

    public void connect() throws SQLException
    {
        String DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
        String URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@xx.xxx.xx.xxx:1521:XXXX";
        String UserName = "username";
        String Password = "password";
        try
        {
            Class.forName(DRIVER);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try
        {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,UserName,Password);
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void disconnect() throws SQLException
    {
        connection.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: You get your error where? when you run it in your app server? or when you run it in eclipse?  Putting the jar in the build path only let you compile without errors.  my guess is your driver is not included in the classpath of your WAR.  you have to put it in your MANIFEST. under WEB-INF

Comment: Yes I get the error when I run it in eclipse. When I add the ojdbc6.jar to WEB-INF folder I get the following error:SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap                 This is even though the Jersey jars are added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using datasources that are managed by the application server, you need to put the `ojdbc6.jar` library inside the `lib` folder of your application server.

On JBoss for example, it would be `$JBOSS_HOME/server/default/lib`.

This is required, because in such case, the datasource is being build when the server starts and independently from your application, which means the server cannot use your application JARs.

If, however, you are pooling the connections yourself, you need to make sure, that the `ojdbc6.jar` is inside the `lib` folder of your application `WAR` archive.